# How can I recompile php with OpenSSL 1.0.1?

Tags: php, openssl

I am trying to implement an PayPay api which will not accept any open SSL version less then 1.0.1.

I am currently developing my web app on MAMP 3.5 but I don't know how to recompile the latest version of OpenSSL on it. Right now the version is 0.98.